# The Binding of Isaac just got harder, but how?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

I have just finished my sixth and seventh full runs of The Binding of Isaac. After completing the sixth run, you do not unlock a new item but instead you just get the "Everything's Terrible!" achievement and the game informs you that it has just gotten harder:

[image: So terrible!]

However, on my seventh playthrough I did not notice anything unusually difficult. Just how does the game change to become more difficult?

Comment: I haven't yet made it to Mom. This game is hard!

Comment: @RavenDreamer Don't give up! The more you play this game, the easier it gets. Not only because you get better, but because you unlock better items over time.

Comment: I killed mom yesterday after 16h

Answer (score 27, accepted):

According to comments on [the wiki](http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Unlockables), "Everything is Terrible" makes alternate colored monsters and bosses more common. This is actually good, because alternate colored monsters tend to leave drops on kill.

According to the [mechanics guide](https://gist.github.com/dpatti/4419061#everything-is-terrible), it also makes Curses more common in Wrath of the Lamb.

Additionally, however, bosses drop one less heart pickup (heart, half-heart, spirit heart) than they previously did.

Answer (score 1):

bosses only drop one health drop instead of two, according to the wiki.

Answer (score 0):

Curses will appear more often (10%).

Comment: Good to know. Where do you get such accurate figures from?